# Clear cell if date in cell is today

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet where I am trying to have multiple things happen when the date in a cell becomes today. I have everything but clearing the date complete. Realized early on that logic in a cell wouldn't work because I still do need to be able to input data into the cell, but I have absolutely no clue how to get an AppSheet running (absolute Sheets newbie here). If any more clarification is needed, I'd be happy to try to elaborate.

Comment: can you share a sample sheet showing the data and expected behaviour/output?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have values on your actual cell and need them to be cleared/disappear, I do have a workaround by using Conditional Formatting.

#### Result:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- The actual values were not deleted, just hidden. Making the value use white font color and white background if value is date today.
- Column `J` are the values with Conditional Rules
- Column `K` are their actual values